# Writing packet information into text file

Tags: networking, lua, wireshark, packet

i wrote the following code to output source address and destination address of all packets that are in a .pcap file to a text file using lua and tshark.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

do
    local file = io.open("luawrite", "w")
    local function init_listener()
            local tap = Listener.new("ipv6")
            function tap.packet(pinfo, tvb)
                    local srcadd = pinfo.src
                    local dstadd = pinfo.dst
                    file:write(tostring(srcadd), "\t", tostring(dstadd)"\n")
            end
    end
end
```

I am running this script using the following command:

```
tshark -r wireless.pcap -xlua_script:MyScript.lua
```

Why is nothing being written in my text file? Is there something wrong on the code? Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you are missing a comma before "\n":

```
---------------------------------------------------vv-----
file:write(tostring(srcadd), "\t", tostring(dstadd), "\n")
```

It may be useful to check for `file` value returned by the `open` call.

I don't see any other problems with the script; if you still have issues, I have a [page on debugging Wireshark Lua scripts](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-wireshark-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio) that may help.